# can't install django using pipenv/unable to create process using python "blah blah"

Tags: python, django

Newbie python learner here. Was following Mosh's guide (yt: /watch?v=rHux0gMZ3Eg&t=804s) but I got stuck in the pipenv part.. I tried a lot of workarounds/solutions but none of them worked (..ones I found so far), I just want to proceed on coding my first web app using Django. The dilemma taught me a lot about virtual environments and dependencies tho, but I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and I wanna move on. Actually, at first, I got to install Django but I was tracing back and redoing the processes to learn and fix the errors on VSCode but it got me a few steps back and I got stuck eventually. Out of frustration, I deleted a couple of files because I had to do reinstallation of Python for both "All users" and "Specific users" - and the paths messed up and so there were Python folder at C:\Programs Files and there were in C:...\Users, so I had to delete the other one. I also deleted a pipfile and pipfile.lock - idk if this was where the problem is but I couldn't generate any pipfile.lock anymore - but maybe it's just because I couldn't install Django.

My setup:

- Windows 11
- Python 10
- Windows Terminal (run as administrator)
- VSCode

What workarounds I did:

- Reinstalled python (both for all users and specific user)
- Reinstalled VScode
- Configured my paths on system environment variables
- Reinstalled and updated pip and pipenv both in root and project folder (storefront)
- Tried python -m pipenv install django
- Tried to remove (by pipenv --rm or by manually deleting in .virtualenv folder) and recreate environment
- Tried to delete pipfile and pipfile.lock

## The Error:

--start--

PS C:\Users\IamUSER\Desktop\storefront> python -m pipenv install django
Installing django...
[    ] Installing...Failed to load paths: Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\IamUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -c "import sysconfig, distutils.sysconfig, io, json, sys; paths = {u'purelib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=0)),u'stdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')),u'platlib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=1)),u'platstdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('platstdlib')),u'include': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=0)),u'platinclude': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=1)),u'scripts': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('scripts')),u'py_version_short': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_version()), }; value = u'{0}'.format(json.dumps(paths));fh = io.open('c:/users/psrcsa~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpx9ufs65t.json', 'w'); fh.write(value); fh.close()"'

Output:
Failed to load paths: Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\IamUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -c "import sysconfig, distutils.sysconfig, io, json, sys; paths = {u'purelib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=0)),u'stdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('stdlib')),u'platlib': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib(plat_specific=1)),u'platstdlib': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('platstdlib')),u'include': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=0)),u'platinclude': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=1)),u'scripts': u'{0}'.format(sysconfig.get_path('scripts')),u'py_version_short': u'{0}'.format(distutils.sysconfig.get_python_version()), }; value = u'{0}'.format(json.dumps(paths));fh = io.open('c:/users/psrcsa~1/appdata/local/temp/tmphvthbvp4.json', 'w'); fh.write(value); fh.close()"'

Output:
Error:  An error occurred while installing django!
Error text:
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\IamUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade --exists-action=i -r "c:\users\IamUSER\appdata\local\temp\pipenv-94y9rddg-requirements\pipenv-yytkqh4g-requirement.txt" -i [https://pypi.org/simple'](https://pypi.org/simple%27)

Installation Failed

--end--

P.S. The paths were correct as I was able to install pip and pipenv, and django using pip in a different folder. It's just this one with pipenv.

P.P.S. Please Hellllp! T^T

Comment: Maybe you can try something simpler first, like running a Python hello world program, and then installing a small component, and request help in smaller bites.

Comment: idk if this is a big bite already but I was just installing a Django thru pipenv. I was just following a tutorial for Python-Django beginners..it's just the setup that's gotten me stuck.

Comment: maybe you can try the old way. `python -m venv venv` and then activate the env by `.\venv\Scripts\activate` and then `pip install django`

Comment: it don't work. it said invalid syntax